# table cell background color and round corners

Tags: html, css, css-tables

In the snippet http://jsfiddle.net/hXMLF/3/ you see a small border on the corners between the white border of the cells and the page background. How can I prevent it?

HTML

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

table {
    margin: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

td {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #369;
    color: white;
    border: 5px solid white;
}​
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two solutions I came up with. **Use solution 2** but I'm keeping solution 1 here as well because it may come in handy in some other situation to someone else.

### Solution 1: Display

Changing `td` display to `inline-block` does the trick but may impact your actual content elsewhere...

```
td {
    display: inline-block; /* this has been added */
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #369;
    color: white;
    border: 5px solid white;
}​
```

Here's [your changed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXMLF/7/) for solution 1.

### Solution 2: Background clip (recommended)

But since you're using CSS3 anyway this is an even better solution:

```
td {
    background-clip: padding-box; /* this has been added */
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #369;
    color: white;
    border: 5px solid white;
}​
```

Here's [your changed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXMLF/10/) for solution 2.

If it doesn't work on all browsers, you should be aware that there are browser specific settings as `-moz-background-clip` and `-webkit-background-clip` that use a different set of values (they basically omit *box* from `border-box`, `padding-box` and `content-box`)

Comment: Solution 2 is perfect, so forget about solution 1.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hXMLF/12/ if I remove the top (or bottom) border, padding-box fix only a part of the clipping bug :(

Comment: @thirtydot: I know. I edited my answer to suggest second one and keeping first one for historical reasons.

Comment: @Nachtgold: Use `content-box` instead that will limit background to content only. Removes glitch as I tested it. But you may see a bit different *inner border roundness* which is arguably a more correct border roundness anyway.

Comment: It does not work quite well when using rounded corners in combination with a box-shadow - at least in Firefox the background color shines through a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

makes it like that. Tables aren't exactly the *prima donna* at styling, I recommend You try to use `<div>` tags instead.

TRY THIS: http://jsfiddle.net/hXMLF/9/

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. You can generate CSS for round corner cell.

**http://cssround.com/**

Example:

```
<div 
style="
width:400px;
height:300px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 26px 0px 0px;
-moz-border-radius:    0px 26px 0px 0px;
border-radius:         0px 26px 0px 0px;
background-color:#C2E3BF;
-webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 2px 2px 2px;
-moz-box-shadow:    #B3B3B3 2px 2px 2px;
box-shadow:         #B3B3B3 2px 2px 2px;
">

Just modify width and height values to get what you need...

</div>
```

Comment: I was not interested in solutions with div elements, because it is a table element specific problem.